# Can my ETH be frozen by Metamask's Validator Staking Contract?

Tags: cryptocurrency, metamask, staking

Does MetaMask have the power to freeze my assets?

I'm not an expert but Validator Staking looks to me like a contract interacting with the beacon chain contract.

Does me investing into Validator Staking give them the power to freeze my ETH as they please? I'm not judging their reputation here, I'm only interested in a technical answer in case some legislation forces them into doing that.

Is just a theoretical question, not something that happend.

Thanks.

Contract here: https://etherscan.io/address/0xdc71affc862fceb6ad32be58e098423a7727bebd#code